# Using summation to calculate the remainder of order 3 of a multivariable function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, summation, taylor-expansion

$R_{p+1}(x) = \sum_{i_1+i_2+...+i_n = p+1} \frac{1}{i_1!i_2!...i_n!} [\frac{\partial^{p+1}f}{\partial x_1^{i_1} x_2^{i_2}...x_n^{i_n}} (c) × (x_1 - x_{0,1})^{i_1} ...(x_n - x_{0,n})^{i_n}]$

where $c \in (x_0,x)$ and $x = (x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$, $x_0 = (x_{0,1},x_{0,2},...x_{0,n})$

$p=2$ in this case and $x_0 = (0,0,0)$

$R_3(x) = \frac{1}{3!}[\frac{\partial^3f}{\partial x_3^3}(c) × x_3^3] + \frac{1}{3!}[\frac{\partial^3f}{\partial x_2^3}(c) × x_2^3] +\frac{1}{3!}[\frac{\partial^3f}{\partial x_1^3}(c) × x_1^3] + \frac{1}{2!} [\frac{\partial^3f}{\partial x_2 x_3^2}(c) × x_2 x_3^2] + \frac{1}{2!}[\frac{\partial^3f}{\partial x_1 x_3^2}(c) × x_1 x_3^2] + \frac{1}{2!}[\frac{\partial^3f}{\partial x_1 x_2^2}(c) × x_1 x_2^2] + \frac{1}{2!}[\frac{\partial^3f}{\partial x_2^2 x_3}(c) × x_2^2 x_3] + \frac{1}{2!}[\frac{\partial^3f}{\partial x_1^2 x_2}(c) × x_1^2 x_2] + \frac{1}{2!}[\frac{\partial^3f}{\partial x_1^2 x_3}(c) × x_1^2 x_3] + \frac{1}{1!}[\frac{\partial^3f}{\partial x_1 x_2 x_3}(c) × x_1 x_2 x_3]$

Is it correct?

And if I'm given the function: $f(x_1, x_2, x_3) = e^{x_1^2 + x_2 + x_1x_3} cos x_1$,

What is $\frac{\partial^3f}{\partial x_3^3}(c)$? If $\frac{\partial^3f}{\partial x_3^3}(x_1,x_2,x_3) = e^{x_1^2 + x_2 + x_1x_3} x_1^3cosx_1$

Comment: Can you list all the $3$-tuples $(i_1,i_2,i_3) \in \{0, \dots, 3\}^3$ such that $i_1+i_2+i_3 = 3$? If yes, you're almost there using permutations.

Comment: The sum is over all tuples $(i_1, i_2, \ldots, i_n)$ for which $i_1+i_2+\ldots i_n = p+1$.

For $p=2$:

$n = 3 \rightarrow i_1 + i_2 + i_3 = 3 \rightarrow (0,0,3), (0,3,0), (1,1,1), \ldots$

Comment: Ok got them: $(0,0,3), (0,3,0), (3,0,0),(1,1,1), (0,1,2), (1,0,2), (1,2,0), (0,2,1), (2,1,0), (2,0,1)$. Now what next?

Comment: I'm gonna edit it the way I did the summation now that I understood what u told me. Can you please check my edit to see if it's correct?

Comment: You can get displayed equations by enclosing them in double instead of single dollar signs. This is especially relevant for legibility if you combine fractions and exponents.